# numbers used as words

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word or words for a group of numbers that is used with a specific meaning apart from the values of the numbers themselves? Like 911 for emergency, 411 for information, 24/7 for always available, or 10-4, 10-20, and similar radio code designations? I know each of these has specific meanings and associations, but I wonder what term/s can be used to refer to this category of numbers used as language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called [**numeronym**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym):  a number based word.

From Wikipedia:

> Less commonly, a numeronym is composed entirely of numbers, such as "212" for "New Yorker", "4-1-1" for "information", "9-1-1" for "help", and "101" for "basic introduction to a subject". Words of this type have existed for decades, including those in 10-code, which has been in use since before World War II.

Comment: @medica Yeah ... me, too.  But, now I live in 203, which I know you remember, too.